# No Tor log details

Tags: configuration, log

Me - 9D60A484CFBDB5B890FB5B18941494734584BA17

I have recently seen this in my `torrc` log

```
Aug 09 16:04:20.000 [notice] Your Tor server's identity key fingerprint is 'Ybslik 9D60A484CFBDB5B890FB5B18941494734584BA17'
Aug 09 16:04:20.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Aug 09 16:04:20.000 [warn] Please upgrade! This version of Tor (0.2.9.10) is not recommended, according to the directory authorities. Recommended versions are: 0.2.5.14,0.2.8.14,0.2.9.11,0.3.0.9,0.3.0.10,0.3.1.5-alpha
```

Being a complete newbie to all this , I searched the net for how to update Tor data.
I found a site that had the code input for use in the terminal. 
(`apt-get upgrade`)
So I tied this and after it downloaded stuff I ran `apt-get upgrade install`.
once that had finished my computer rebooted and when I had restored the tor browser I went to Altlas where I saw that my Tor was still showing the outdated data, after 30 mins or so It showed that my system was now up to date No error messages.
It was then I went to check the log   `/var/log/tor`, saw the files `Log`, `Log.1`, `log.2.gz`, `log.3.gz` through to `log.5.gz`
I opened up the `Log` file and it was blank, I went and opened up the `log.1` file and it had the final throws of the Tor before it shut down.
I thought it may be a hiccup and I waited now for 2 days and still I have nothing in my log yet Atlas shows I have been up and running again for 2 days 15 hrs.
Can you help me get back my log files so I can monitor what tor is doing please.
As you my have deduced, I do not have the skills yet to use the terminal without detailed help.
Any help would be most welcome

Steve

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you running? And can you be more specific as to the commands that you ran or where you found them?

Comment: Thank you.....I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xential
I created an account in Stackexchange and made a question back in May 14 this year and Peter Gerber gave me the code ( i hadn't put the full version in my original text as I was using memory) the text he gave me was 
Tor version  dpkg -l tor
which now gives me    -     0.3.0.9-1~xe  amd64  anonymizing overlay network for T
Update apt-get update && apt-get upgrade.

Steve

Comment: I believe that on Ubuntu tor now logs to syslog (systemd journal) by default, to view the logs run the command `sudo journalctl -u tor@default`

Comment: I can see the log, thanks, this used to be in /var/log/tor which is now blank, i now have a notices.log which is what used to be in the blank log file? i have been trying to understand what i should be running. I have viewed a youtube video "how to create and run a Tor middle relay on Ubuntu"

Comment: I can see the log, thanks, this used to be in /var/log/tor which is now blank, i now have a notices.log which is what used to be in the blank log file? i have been trying to understand what i should be running. I have viewed a youtube video "how to create and run a Tor middle relay on Ubuntu"  I had done most of what is described but he stated that by allowing in the Torrc file  under mirror directory DirPort 9030 it would help.......so that is what I did.  I am now looking at the Notices.log its saying  [warn] your server (82.3.6.169:9030) has not managed to confirm its DirPort is reachable.

Comment: It does look like that port isn't available, you don't need to expose a dirport (infact in future I think its going to be more or less deprecated) but it's possible that there's some port forwarding that hasn't been setup or a firewall or packet filter in the way on your network?

Comment: Ok Thanks, # the DirPort out.   is - service tor restart - the correct method of restarting Tor, will it pick up the new torrc file I just saved, or do I have to completely shut down the computer and restart it?  also what's the difference between an Orport and a DirPort

Comment: Simply issuing `service tor restart` will restart the tor process entirely. Often for simply configuration changes you can just do `service tor reload` though. A DirPort serves HTTP directory requests (e.g. information about relays on the network) and an ORPort is what serves Tor users traffic and connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updating Tor

First of all, you need to update Tor. I would recommend installing experimental versions. As for that do the following:

> You need to add the following entry in /etc/apt/sources.list or a new
>   file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/:
>
> ```
> deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial main
> deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial main
> deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.3.1.x-xenial main
> deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.3.1.x-xenial main
> ```
>
> Then add the gpg key used to sign the packages by running the
>   following commands at your command prompt:
>
> ```
> gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
> gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> You can install it with the following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
> ```

Or, if you prefer installing stable versions, remove those lines from previous text:

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.3.1.x-xenial main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.3.1.x-xenial main
```

## Viewing log files

Those log files ending with `.gz` are the gzip archives.
To see those, you need to run:

```
gzip -d ./*.gz
```

Make sure that you are in the Tor directory.

After that, you should be fine. If you still have questions, comment them!